# Set intervals for fadeout/show jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make one div fade out after 5 seconds, and then have a new div appear with JQuery.

Here is my current code: https://pastebin.com/M7D6qMWi

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function hidehero(){
        $("#hero").fadeOut();
    };
    function showmain(){
        $("main").show();
    };
    function timeouts(){
        setInterval(hidehero(), 3000);
        setInterval(showmain(), 5000);
    };
    timeouts();
});
```

Unfortunately, the first div just instantly disappears and the new div instantly appears, and it isnt listening to the intervals.

If anyone knows how to fix this let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
setInterval(hidehero(), 3000);
setInterval(showmain(), 5000);
```

with:

```
//Pass the function, not the return value of the function.
setInterval(hidehero, 3000);
setInterval(showmain, 5000);
```

You're calling the function instantly that's why it isnt working as expected. `setInterval` takes a `function` as its first parameter, and you're passing `undefined` since `hidehero` function doesn't return anything.

BTW you should use `setTimeout` and not `setInterval`, in your code there is no need to call hidehero every 3 seconds.

Your `showmain` function is also wrong, since you're missing `#` in `$("main")`. To reference an ID in jQuery use `$("#main")`

Here's a working demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 function hidehero() {
  $("#hero").fadeOut();
 };

 function showmain() {
  $("#main").show();
 };

 function timeouts() {
  setTimeout(hidehero, 3000);
  setTimeout(showmain, 5000);
 };
 timeouts();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Sevi Home</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png"  href="favicon.ico" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="hero">
    <div class="header">SEVI<br></div>
</div>
<div id="main" style="display:none"><div class="header2">ELLO!!!!!!</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Change setInterval() for setTimeout() and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#hero").fadeOut(function() {
            $("#main").show();
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```